# Create geometric design in Android layout using XML only

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I want to create a geometric design like [this](https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/256x256/Circle_Red.png) in Android using XML only.
[image: Icon]

What I've already tried:

- <shape> in drawable resource, but I did not get even close to the
  solution.
- Used Canvas and java backend to draw this. I was able to achieve what I wanted but, I was not able to verify the result on different resolution screens. Since there is a backend involved, I need to create emulator for each screensize and deploy my activity to see the result.

What I want is an approach where I can implement this in purely design layer. What should I try?

Comment: does it have to be `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` ?

Comment: so how do you want to use it?

Comment: in my layout, I want to show it within relative layout.

Comment: as a background (`View.setBackground`)?

Comment: it can be just anything, as long as it is displayed. I tried it as background using shape and as view element using canvas.

Comment: so what is wrong with those two approaches?